# How to analyze which processes are creating (short-lived) local network connections to my service?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010, wcf, sockets

Is there a Windows (7) tool that traces which processes are creating local network connections to my service on the same machine?

Since a couple of weeks I'm seeing the creation of lots and lots of sockets that immediately (or at least very fast) get the status TIME_WAIT. This does not happen always, but regularly, haven't been able to find a pattern yet. I'm using `netstat -a -b -n -o` to find information about those sockets, but the only things that tells me is the end-point (which is my service), the status (always TIME_WAIT) and that the owning process is process 0, so not very useful.

There are of course other methods for analyzing this problem, but having a tool that pinpoints the exact process that creates this huge amount of sockets, will narrow down my search.

Some more background information: my service is an ECO WCF service connected to SQL Server Express 2008 R2. There are four web sites running locally in Visual Studio's WebDev.WebServer40.EXE, all of them will use the service at one time or another.
First I suspected a bug/bit rot in Visual Studio 2010 or my Windows 7 setup, so I did a fresh install, but the problems was still there.
Going back to previous versions of my service and applications does not fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always have a look at a very handy tool called [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx). It was developed by Mark Russinovich, and is now part of a Microsoft toolset.

It allows you to monitor lots of events, including thread creation, registry access, file access, and network activity.  All of these events are on a per-process basis, so you should be able to use the filters to see what process is connecting to a specific port local port.  I'm not sure if this would include UDP (which is generally connectionless), but certainly a quick test shows TCP Connect, Disconnect, Send and Receive events.

It's a very handy tool to add to your programming toolbox anyway.

Comment: Brilliant! Exactly what I was looking for, thanks!
The culprit was the service itself: it was constantly connecting and disconnecting to itself. I'm now trying to find out why.

Comment: Just to make the history complete for future searches: the problem was caused by the Eco service itself trying to sync a lot of data to another database (this is by design) combined with Visual Studio's dev webserver. When I switched to IIS Express the problem was gone.